# Fill empty object with part of the data from another object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, nested

I have an empty object that's represented like this:

```
myObj = {
 myObjName = null;
 myObjType = null;
 myObjOcc = null;
}
```

And there is an object with objects represented like this:

```
mainObj = {
    "Ob1": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Ob1",
        "properties": {
            "attName": "A1",
            "attType": "string",
            "attOccurance": "minOccurs="1""
        },
    },
    "Ob2": {
         "id": 101,
         "name": "Ob2",
         "properties": {
             "attName": "B1",
             "attType": "string",
             "attOccurance": "minOccurs="1""
         },
     }
     "Ob3": {
          "id": 10001,
          "name": "Ob3",
          "properties": {
              "attName": "C1",
              "attType": "string",
              "attOccurance": "minOccurs="1""
              },
       }
}
```

I have to insert the data from the objects in **mainObj** to **myObj**.

The mapping is supposed to be like this:

```
myObjName = attName
myObjType = attType
myObjOcc = attOccurance
```

Another thing taken into account has to be **id** in mainObj, because **Ob2** has to be nested inside **Ob1** and **Ob3** has to be nested inside **Ob2**

So myObj is suppose to look like this:

```
myObj = {
    "Ob1": {
        "myObjName": "A1",
        "myObjType": "string",
        "myObjOcc": "minOccurs="1""
        "Ob2": {
            "myObjName": "B1",
            "myObjType": "string",
            "myObjOcc": "minOccurs="1""
            "Ob3": {
                "myObjName": "C1",
                "myObjType": "string",
                "myObjOcc": "minOccurs="1""
            }
        }
   }
}
```

I have this part in the code that determines which level is every object:

```
for each(var oneObj in mainObj){
    .
    .
    switch (true) {
                 case  oneObj.id < 100: levelId=1; break;
                 case  oneObj.id < 10000: levelId=2; break;
                 case  oneObj.id < 1000000: levelId=3; break;
    }
    .
    .
}
```

Please if anyone can help me how can I do this?

Comment: *So myObj is suppose to look like this: .....* The sample doesn't look nested to me. You just made some indentation illusion

Comment: Sorry, you're right, it's fixed

Answer (score 0):

What you're saying are objects look an awful like JSON. However, here's how you'd accomplish what you say you want the result to be.

```js
// var myObj = {};
// for (key in mainObj) {
//   const name = mainObj[key].name
//   myObj[name] = {
//     myObjName: mainObj[key].properties.attName,
//     myObjType: mainObj[key].properties.attType,
//     myObjOcc: mainObj[key].properties.attOccurance
//   }
// }

// console.log(myObj)

var mainObj = {
    Ob1: {
        id: 1,
        name: "Ob1",
        properties: {
            attName: "A1",
            attType: "string",
            attOccurance: 'minOccurs="1"'
        },
    },
    Ob2: {
        id: 101,
        name: "Ob2",
        properties: {
            attName: "B1",
            attType: "string",
            attOccurance: 'minOccurs="1"'
        },
    },
    Ob3: {
        id: 10001,
        name: "Ob3",
        properties: {
            attName: "C1",
            attType: "string",
            attOccurance: 'minOccurs="1"'
        },
    }
}

var myObj = {};
for (key in mainObj) {
  const name = mainObj[key].name
  myObj[name] = {
    myObjName: mainObj[key].properties.attName,
    myObjType: mainObj[key].properties.attType,
    myObjOcc: mainObj[key].properties.attOccurance
  }
}

console.log(myObj)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in this solution, the objects are not nested inside each other.
How can I do that using the levelId inside case function?